# Unable to access rails localhost running on AWS Ubuntu from my Windows desktop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running Rails server on an AWS Ubuntu instance. And I am trying to access the server from a browser on my Windows desktop. This used to work perfectly fine until yesterday. I started to get a blank page on my browser since yesterday with this message:

```
This site can’t be reached The webpage at http://10.110.104.76:3000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED
```

This is what I see when I start my rails server:

```
rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.7.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.4.4-p296), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Am completely baffled - why would it work fine all these months and suddenly stop working since yesterday? Please help!

I even tried running

```
sudo ufw allow 3000
```

to allow port access to port 3000 but no luck!

When I started rails with my IP, I get this error:

```
rails s -b 10-110-104-76
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.7.1 application starting in development on http://10-110-104-76:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.4.4-p296), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://10-110-104-76:3000
Exiting
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:272:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution (SocketError)
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:272:in `new'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:272:in `add_tcp_listener'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:105:in `block in parse'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `each'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `parse'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:151:in `load_and_bind'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/single.rb:96:in `run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:184:in `run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:70:in `run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:104:in `start'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/rails/ActiveJob-Report-Generation/cfps_app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/rails/ActiveJob-Report-Generation/cfps_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/rails/ActiveJob-Report-Generation/cfps_app/bin/spring:15:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/rails/ActiveJob-Report-Generation/cfps_app/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: try running your server by `rails s -b 10.110.104.76` and see if you can access. Also check nginx/passenger log. It seems like your server moved to a new IP

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try that. But am pretty sure my Ubuntu IP has not changed (because I use putty to login to my Ubuntu instance and I use pre-stored IP/config to login. If the IP had changed, I would not be able to login to my Ubuntu instance)

Comment: @G.B - I tried your suggestion - I get a different error - I've updated my question with the error. Pls help!

Comment: there is problem in your command instead of `rails s -b 10-110-104-76` do `rails s -b 10.110.104.76`

Comment: Thanks @G.B - I fixed my command but I get ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED (the original error in my question) again